# inserting an item into a database using a foreign key

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two different files that deal with this
I have a post.php file (url looks like post.php?id=(number)) that deals with the form on the page of the parent message

```
<form id="chardiv" action="comments.php" method="post">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="mod_name" required><br>

Message:<br>

<textarea class='autoExpand' rows='3' data-min-rows='3' placeholder='Auto-Expanding Textarea' name="topic" required></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
</form>
```

and a second file "comments.php" which the html form posts too

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';
$conn    = Connect();
$id    = (int)$_GET['id'];
$comment   = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['topic']);
$date    = time();
$query   = "INSERT into anon_comments (post_id,Date,comment) VALUES('" . $id . "','" . $date . "','" . $comment . "')";
$success = $conn->query($query);

if (!$success) {
    die("Couldn't enter data: ".$conn->error);
}
$conn->close();
header('Location: /index.php');
?>
```

which deals with the posting to the database

I'm unsure how I would go about sending the foreign key (parents id) to the database from the page the form is on.

can someone give aid
Thanks!

[image: database]

[image: result on the webpage]

Comment: what is your question ? it is not at all clear. Could you specifically point out ? any error/exception ?

Comment: "I'm unsure how I would go about sending the foreign key (parents id) to the database from the page the form is on."

Comment: You are already using `post.php?id=` . right ?

Comment: to get to the webpage with the post on it yeah, then I'm retrieving the id from the url and using that to get the parent post from the database, but if I'm to link comments to the parent post i need to reference the foreign key in the comment storage

Comment: website url looks something like www.website.com/post.php?id=1 for example

Comment: ok so what is your problem ? your question is not clear. You need to show your page flow and point out your issue

Comment: What DB driver are you using `mysqli`? from the look of it.  Just FYI, PDO is soooo much better.  My Opinion.

Comment: alright give me a minute

Comment: standard one that comes with xampp? i assume thats what you're asking

Comment: I added images that show what I'm aiming for and how its set up in the database, the form that is shown on the webpage is the form I've given the code for and that form links to the php code in another file which will save to the database once i finish it, I'm just not sure how to pass the foreign key from the form page to the file which sends it to the database

Comment: `onSubmit="window.location.reload()"` <- WTF?

Comment: that doesnt do anything need to remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing wrong here. you have to pass your id in :
`<input type="hidden" name="id" value="YOUR VALUE" />`

and on **comments.php** page get the value by `$id = (int)$_POST['id'];`

Hope it helps!!

Comment: ahh okay ill try this!

Comment: my value needs to be dependant on the posts id for would it be something like

<input type="hidden" name="id" <?php value="'$foo'" ?>/>

Comment: It should be like this :
`<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $foo; ?> "/>`

Comment: im not gertting this error 
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Clickerbox\comments.php on line 4
Couldn't enter data: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`clickerbox`.`anon_comments`, CONSTRAINT `anon_comments_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Post_ID`) REFERENCES `anon_post` (`ID`))

Comment: on comments.php , are you getting the value of id ?

Comment: and the id is exists in database table (of your main post table ) ?

Comment: this is comments.php

<?php
require 'connect.php';
$conn    = Connect();
$id    = (int)$_GET['id'];
$comment   = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['topic']);
$date    = time();
$query   = "INSERT into anon_comments (post_id,Date,comment) VALUES('" . $id . "','" . $date . "','" . $comment . "')";
$success = $conn->query($query);

if (!$success) {
    die("Couldn't enter data: ".$conn->error);
}
$conn->close();
header('Location: /index.php');
?>

Comment: change `$id = (int)$_GET['id']; ` to `$id = (int)$_POST['id']; `

Comment: yeah if you look at the screenshots i post the original post has an id of 23 and so thats what im trying to save back in the comments.php as foreign key